# php script return nothing if to much information

Tags: php, mysql, json

I try with the JSON data from MYSQL read by PHP script. so it is, everything works, but if I put too much data what PHP script must read he return empty side, and JSON cant get any information ... I am not very good in php but maybe it is something like execution query time limit or the array to long?

here is my php

```
<?php
$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM weltvonhalva") or die(mysql_error());
    $response["weltvonhalva"] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $weltvonhalva = array();
        $weltvonhalva["id"] = $row["id"];
        $weltvonhalva["nachricht"] = $row["nachricht"];
        array_push($response["weltvonhalva"], $weltvonhalva);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`set_time_limit (0);`

command at the beginning of your PHP-script. It will set infinite execution time.

Comment: its not helping. my code is working with 80 rows, but if i get more than 100 rows, he show nothing, and normally execution time with 80 rows less than 1sec. :(

Comment: @ArturPiroschkow do you have blank response?

Comment: yes, exactly. in my php ini settings i have limit 20sec. if i need for 80 rows less than 1sec, i dont think that for 100 rows i need mor than 20sec.. i just dont know what that should be :(

Comment: @ArturPiroschkow Look in browser network section what kind of HTTP status is returned. Is it 500 error?

Comment: if i open it with firefox, this link, is that just empty... if i remove somelines from database, he show again some information..

Comment: @ArturPiroschkow Try to investigate response on this panel https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

Comment: @ArturPiroschkow You should determine response status, if it is 500 it means you have internal server error.

Comment: is show me everything empty no errors.. i think it is maybe becaus the array to long? or to much information in string with gib me php skript?